# How can I send a notification in electron?

Tags: node.js, electron

Using electron / node.js for desktop application. Trying to figure out how to produce a notification on the desktop. Is it built into the electron API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Electron allows developers to push notifications using the HTML5 Notification API.

Example:

```
let myNotification = new Notification('Foo', {
  body: 'Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet'
})

myNotification.onclick = () => {
  console.log('Notification clicked')
}
```

Since Windows 7 does not support notifications, take a look at the the [tray](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/tray/) object documentation instead.

You can find more information on this [here](https://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/desktop-environment-integration/)

**Also:**

Take a look at [node-notifier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-notifier) plugin which is easier to use and also is cross platform.

Answer (score 13):

`node-notifier` made easier to send native notifications. Node notifier A Node.js module for sending notifications on native Mac, Windows, and Linux (or Growl as fallback).

[Github](https://github.com/mikaelbr/node-notifier)

#### Install:

```
npm install --save node-notifier
```

#### Example:

```
const notifier = require('node-notifier');
// String
notifier.notify('Message');

// Object
notifier.notify({
  title: 'My notification',
  message: 'Hello, there!'
});
```

#### Notification:

[image]

Comment: Never done a task like that. But it's possible. @RahulMatte

Comment: this library also suffers from the problem that in win10, you need to have an "appId" in order to be able to show toasts. And you can obtain that only by using electrons official installer... I hate this OS

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
const {Notification} = require('electron');

function callNotification(){
    let iconAddress = path.join(__dirname, '/icon.png');
    const notif={
          title: 'Headline',
          body: 'Here write your message',
          icon: iconAddress
        };
    new Notification(notif).show();
}
```